# Processing SSAS cube,how it works?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, partitioning

One doubt while processing the SSAS cube, if the table contained in it has the partitions, and user selects "Process Full" as processing mode, what exactly happens- 
      - Whether only table partitions get process **OR** 
      - the table processed with respect to its source query (from table properties its just a select query which meant for a source for the table).
 I am assuming only partitions should be processed ? Correct me if I am missing something here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A full process will drop all aggregations , structures and indexes and then pull in the data according to the partition specifications (if any)

Comment: So as I understood, If there is partition specified then though processing mode is "Full Process" , table will get processed via Partitions only. Just to confirm. :)